# Use aware datetime object in all backend code

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

For some time we have been using `datetime.now()`, `datetime.utcnow()` and `datetime.today()` randomly in the code. For now it is okay since all servers in all regions run in UTC time.

Recently we decided to use `datetime.now(timezone=utc)` to make it timezone "aware" instead of "naive" after reading this Python doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime (first warning part)

Question:
For datetime retrieved from DB, it seems we will have to add `.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)` at the end to make it timezone "aware". (Otherwise, an error would show up saying it is a comparison between a naive object and an aware object)
For example:

```
user = User.get_user_by_id('123')
if user.expires_at.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc) < datetime.now(timezone.utc):
 print('Expires.')
```

Is there any way I can do the same thing without having to add `.replace(tzinfo=datetime.utc)?`

Comment: Why would you use pytz? `datetime.timezone.utc` does the same an would avoid having to import pytz

Comment: Yes timezone.utc. Thanks. Just updated.